# Is a list a column or row?

Tags: haskell

I'm very confused. Reading Data.List package, it says:

transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] -->
[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]

Which would mean that every list is a row?

Reading other literature it seems that a list is in fact a column. Which one is it?

Comment: What literature? Whether a row or a list or a column depends on how you interpret the nested lists. Either way, `transpose` turns one into the other. It's not necessarily immediately related to matrix transposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. A list is a sequence. We can pretend it is a row, or a column, but that's an arbitrary choice.

`transpose` takes a list of lists as input. We can think of that as a sequence of rows, forming a matrix (or a "jagged" matrix if rows are of unequal size). The result, interpreted in the same way, is the transposed matrix.

If we want, we can *also* see the input of `transpose` as a sequence of columns, forming a matrix. The result, if we interpret it in the same way, is again the transposed matrix.

TL;DR: for `transpose` it does not matter if we see the list of lists as a list/sequence of rows of a matrix, or a list/sequence of columns of a matrix, as long as we interpret the result in the same way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :)